# Python: Import networkx as nx: Global name not defined

Tags: python, import, networkx

I wrote a module (processing_0) in which I import all packages and modules required for my project.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
import la
import csv
import fishery
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

import processing_1
import processing_2
import processing_3

from processing_1 import readingraph, readinpathgraph, preparefisher, inEEG
from processing_2 import pathwayprofile
from processing_3 import checkkin
from fishery import fisher
```

The modules that I wrote (processing_1/2/3) all require access to networkx (nx).

As part of the master module, I have a the startup function:

```
def startup():

  EEG = readingraph("/.../file1")
  EET = readingraph("/.../file2")
  EEL = readingraph("/.../file3")

  return EEG, EET, EEL
```

However, after importing processing_0 and trying to run startup() that uses readingraph from processing_1, I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "processing_0.py", line 31, in startup
    EEG = readingraph("/.../file1")
  File "processing_1.py", line 4, in process
    graph = nx.read_adjlist(filename)
NameError: global name 'nx' is not defined
```

Is there any way to globally import networkx as nx and make it accessible to all imported modules?

Comment: Error is in the file `processing_1.py`. Not in the `processing_0.py` whose code you included

Comment: *"Is there any way to globally import networkx as nx ..."* - No. Just import it in `processing_1.py` etc.

Comment: That would be a bad idea if it were possible because someone looking at processing_1.py code needs to know where things come from. Things like `nx`. Things that are used in the module should be imported in the module for two good reasons: first, by looking at imports you get an idea of what's used in the module, second -- as I mentioned -- if you see a line using a module you can easily find where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using linux ubuntu, do these followings in order.

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install python-networkx
3. go to pycharm env and > file>setting> interpreter and structure to
   configure your python env and add packages, there is all packages
   that are in env, then click on + to add newpackage
4. type networkx in search text box, and then select it from package
   list and click on install
5. after finish it , click ok and close windows

Answer (score 0):

In every file that you use networkx you need to import it. So just repeat the line
import networkx as nx
inside the file processing_1.py